# Excel Density Map

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a density map in excel.  The map will be in a seperate worksheet then where the data is stored.  The problem I am having right now is being able to access the data in a separate worksheet then the one my vba function is running in.  I thought I could do it like this:

```
Dim row As Range

' Loop through rows 4 -> 550
For x = 4 To 550
    Set row = Worksheet(1).Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 24)) ' get range of cells for further processing
Next Counter
```

the problem is when I run the code just to test it is getting something excel returns the follow error about "Worksheet(1)":

> Compile Error:
>
> Sub or Function not defined

All my data is stored in Worksheet #1 and the density map is being created in Worksheet #6.  How can i go about doing this

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using this

```
Set row = Worksheets(1).Cells(x,1).Resize(1,24)
```

The Range reference is qualified by Worksheets(1) so it will always point to a range on that worksheet.  Your Cells references are unqualified and will point to a range on the ActiveSheet, which you may not want.

Answer (score 0):

My bad I was calling worksheet(index) instead of worksheets(index) <- notice that this is plural, there is an "s" at the end of worksheet.